# Can not access Samba server from Windows 11 after server reinstall

Tags: rhel, samba, cockpit, almalinux

I recently reinstalled my Alma Linux server, before the reinstall I had a samba share working as intended between my two machines. Unfortunately after the reinstall I can't seem to get them to want to connect back together.

smb.conf

```ini
# Note:
# SMB1 is disabled by default. This means clients without support for SMB2 or
# SMB3 are no longer able to connect to smbd (by default).

[global]
#       workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        include = registry
        map to guest = never
        guest ok = no

#       printing = cups
#       printcap name = cups
#       load printers = yes
#       cups options = raw

#[homes]
#       comment = Home Directories
#       valid users = %S, %D%w%S
#       browseable = No
#       read only = No
#       inherit acls = Yes
#
#[printers]
#       comment = All Printers
#       path = /var/tmp
#       printable = Yes
#       create mask = 0600
#       browseable = No
#
#[print$]
#       comment = Printer Drivers
#       path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
#       write list = @printadmin root
#       force group = @printadmin
#       create mask = 0664
#       directory mask = 0775
```

I commented out most of the conf to try to narrow down on what the issue could be. I *think* I did the same last install.

Here is the error I get on windows, If I try multiple times I seem to get different error messages.

[image: Windows Error 1]

I setup this share from RHEL cockpit, but I'm comfortable with cli if its required. Note if I check windows ACLs below, it removes valid users. I'm sure I didn't use that feature last time.

[image]

Running `sudo testparm` returned the following

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        registry shares = Yes
        security = USER
        server string = 
        workgroup = SAMBA
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[number$]
        path = /shares/number$
        read only = No
        valid users = @aiden @evan aiden evan
        vfs objects = shadow_copy2
        shadow: format = %Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S
        shadow: sort = desc
        shadow: snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
```

Comment: To add, I get also get a unique error message if I put in my password wrong, so at bare minimum I'm being authenticated.

Comment: Running `net use W: \\192.0.9.254\number$` with an incorrect password throws `System error 86 has occurred.
The specified network password is not correct.` While running it with a correct password throws `System error 59 has occurred.
An unexpected network error occurred.`

Comment: If I remove a user via cockpit (screenshot 2) and try to login Ill get the proper System error 5 Access is denied. At this point I'm spinning circles. Incredibly confused on why nothing is working.

Comment: Running `sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=aiden,password=*********,domain=SAMBA //192.0.9.254/number ~/Test` nets me `mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.0.9.254,unc=\\192.0.9.254\number,user=aiden,domain=SAMBA,pass=********`, but when I try to `ls` the files it returns `ls: reading directory '.': Permission denied`